# USB Filesystem that can run executables and can mount on Linux and OS X

Tags: linux, macos, filesystems, mount

I'm looking for a filesystem that I can format a USB drive with that can run C++ executables.

Tried FAT32:

```
$ ./main
bash: ./main: Permission denied
```

Tried NTFS:

```
$ ./main
bash: ./main: Permission denied
```

Tried Ext4: Works, however not mountable on OS X.

Any ideas?

(I also tried chmodding, doesn't work)

Comment: [You're guessing at the answer to your problem and then asking why the answer doesn't work, and of course the guess is wrong.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)  Put the output of `mount ; pwd ; ls -ld ./main ; file ./main` in your question, and answerers will be able to tell you exactly what's happening here.

Comment: @JdeBP That's an absurd assumption. I'm simply telling you **what I've tried**. You were just looking for a place to use that link.

Comment: It's not an assumption, absurd or otherwise.  Your erroneous guess is right there in the title and the first sentence of the question.  M. Knight saw it, too.  Put down the chocolate-covered banana, step away from the European currency systems, and give answerers the information from which they can give you the answer.

Comment: @JdeBP well, I found a file system, UDF. And it works. Perfectly. I **said** i tried chmodding. **there is nothing wrong with the permissions.**

Comment: There's yet another error, right there.  No-one has told you to run `chmod`.  And three of those important diagnostic commands don't even deal in permissions.  Stop fixating on your erroneous guess as to the cause and put the information that will help people to help you in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the FS, it is the permissions on your OSx computer.

Is there a group you need to be in that allows access? Check also that the mount is giving the correct permissions.

Both FAT and NTFS should work and be usable across multiple OS's. NTFS is best if you don't need access from older Windows machines as it gives better security on the Windows side & is closer to the capabilities of Linux/OSx filing systems.